# Unable to run VCenter powershell script

Tags: powershell, vmware

I am trying to connect to VCenter to pull some performance data. When I execute the the script from the powershell window, I get errors:

This is my script:

```
Connect-VIServer "vcenter.server.com" -User user123 -Password testpassword
$allvms = @()
$allhosts = @()
$hosts = Get-VMHost
$vms = Get-Vm

foreach($vmHost in $hosts){
  $hoststat = "" | Select HostName, MemMax, MemAvg, MemMin, CPUMax, CPUAvg, CPUMin
  $hoststat.HostName = $vmHost.name

  $statcpu = Get-Stat -Entity ($vmHost)-start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10 -stat cpu.usage.average
  $statmem = Get-Stat -Entity ($vmHost)-start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10 -stat mem.usage.average

  $cpu = $statcpu | Measure-Object -Property value -Average -Maximum -Minimum
  $mem = $statmem | Measure-Object -Property value -Average -Maximum -Minimum

  $hoststat.CPUMax = $cpu.Maximum
  $hoststat.CPUAvg = $cpu.Average
  $hoststat.CPUMin = $cpu.Minimum
  $hoststat.MemMax = $mem.Maximum
  $hoststat.MemAvg = $mem.Average
  $hoststat.MemMin = $mem.Minimum
  $allhosts += $hoststat
}
$allhosts | Select HostName, MemMax, MemAvg, MemMin, CPUMax, CPUAvg, CPUMin | Export-Csv "c:\output\Hosts.csv" -noTypeInformation

foreach($vm in $vms){
  $vmstat = "" | Select VmName, MemMax, MemAvg, MemMin, CPUMax, CPUAvg, CPUMin
  $vmstat.VmName = $vm.name

  $statcpu = Get-Stat -Entity ($vm)-start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10 -stat cpu.usage.average
  $statmem = Get-Stat -Entity ($vm)-start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10-stat mem.usage.average

  $cpu = $statcpu | Measure-Object -Property value -Average -Maximum -Minimum
  $mem = $statmem | Measure-Object -Property value -Average -Maximum -Minimum

  $vmstat.CPUMax = $cpu.Maximum
  $vmstat.CPUAvg = $cpu.Average
  $vmstat.CPUMin = $cpu.Minimum
  $vmstat.MemMax = $mem.Maximum
  $vmstat.MemAvg = $mem.Average
  $vmstat.MemMin = $mem.Minimum
  $allvms += $vmstat
}
$allvms | Select VmName, MemMax, MemAvg, MemMin, CPUMax, CPUAvg, CPUMin | Export-Csv "c:\output\VMs.csv" -noTypeInformation
```

These are the error:

```
The term 'Connect-VIServer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Chec
k the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\scripts\vm.ps1:1 char:17
+ Connect-VIServer <<<<  dc1prhsvspvc-01 -User haquem -Password Basketball1
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-VIServer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The term 'Get-VMHost' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\scripts\vm.ps1:4 char:20
+ $hosts = Get-VMHost <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-VMHost:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The term 'Get-Vm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spel
ling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\scripts\vm.ps1:5 char:14
+ $vms = Get-Vm <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Vm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The term 'Get-Stat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the sp
elling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\scripts\vm.ps1:11 char:22
+   $statcpu = Get-Stat <<<<  -Entity ($vmHost)-start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10 -stat cpu
.usage.average
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Stat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The term 'Get-Stat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the sp
elling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\scripts\vm.ps1:12 char:22
+   $statmem = Get-Stat <<<<  -Entity ($vmHost)-start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10 -stat mem
.usage.average
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Stat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am very new to powershell, I really appreciate any help with this?

Comment: Do you have VMWare's PowerCLI installed? `Connect-VIServer` is a cmdlet provided by that software, so either it's not installed, the module can't be loaded (if it's a module), or the Snap-In isn't loaded (if it's a Snap-In).

Comment: install this: https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/automationtools/powercli

Comment: @Donal, thank you for the link. I have a quick question. How would I retrieve the time associated with the metrics. For example, I am retrieving cpu, mem etc but I need to know the time with the values. Any ideas?

Comment: In your script you are specifying the time - which is a day - the previous day from today. This bit: (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)

Comment: You are asking for the average stats over the past 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already installed the PowerCLI snap-in ....

You need to use `Add-PSSnapIn` to add the VMware vCenter snap-in for PowerShell. Last I checked, it still uses the old snap-in model instead of the newer module structure.

You should have a Start Menu shortcut to launch the VMware PowerShell console, which should automatically add the snap-in for you.

Comment: cli was missing, I installed, now I can connect to the vcenter, however, it is taking a very long time to run through this script. I need to run this script every 1 hour and get aggregated 5 minitues data. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, you can scheduled PowerShell scripts to run in the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: sorry that's not what I meant. This line: $statcpu = Get-Stat -Entity ($vm)-start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10 -stat cpu.usage.average how would I modify this to extract only last hour of data with 5 minute aggregated data?

Answer (score 0):

## Install vmware "PowerCli" module

On my laptop (winver.exe => *Windows 10 Enterprise Version 21H2*) I ran this in an admin powershell:

```
PS C:\> Install-Module -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Core -verbose -Force -AllowClobber
```

I used `-Force` to suppress prompt.

And I used `-AllowClobber` because without it I got this error:

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : The following commands are already available on this system:'Get-Cluster,New-Cluster,Remove-Cluster'. This module 'VMware.VimAutomation.Core' may override the existing commands. If you still want to install this module
'VMware.VimAutomation.Core', use -AllowClobber parameter.
```

**Further reading:**

- https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.esxi.install.doc/GUID-F02D0C2D-B226-4908-9E5C-2E783D41FE2D.html
- VMware's "get-cluster" collides with Microsoft's "get-cluster": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/get-cluster

## Add REQUIRES statement to script for nicer error messages

In newer PowerShell versions you can do this:

Add this line to the top of our script ("Get-Vms.ps" in this example):

```
#Requires -Modules VMware.VimAutomation.Core
```

Then if you try to run the script without having that module installed, you don't get a bunch of weird error messages, but instead get a single straight-forward error message:

```
PS C:\> .\Get-VMs.ps1
.\Get-VMs.ps1 : The script 'Get-VMs.ps1' cannot be run because the following modules that are specified by the "#requires" statements of the script are missing: VMware.VimAutomation.Core.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\Get-VMs.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Get-VMs.ps1:String) [], ScriptRequiresException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptRequiresMissingModules
```

**Further reading:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires